# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, insert

I'm trying to insert some variables into my database, but I'm getting this error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, could you help me? Thanks in advance

```
import mysql.connector as co
import time as tm
dbConnect = {
    'host':'mx102.hostgator.mx',
    'port':'3306',
    'user':'meandmic_root',
    'password':'abcde',
    'database':'meandmic_analizador'
}

felicidad = 0
enojo = 0
sorpresa = 0
tristeza = 0
neutral = 0
dt = tm.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
conexion = co.connect(**dbConnect)
cursor = conexion.cursor()
sqlInsertar = "insert into registros(CFELICIDAD,CENOJO,CSORPRESA,CTRISTEZA,CNEUTRAL,FECHA)values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(sqlInsertar,[felicidad,enojo,sorpresa,tristeza,neutral,dt])
conexion.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your list to tuple:

```
cursor.execute(sqlInsertar,(felicidad,enojo,sorpresa,tristeza,neutral,dt))
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mikhail Ilin mentioned, the [cursor.execute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) method expects a tuple as the second parameter.

The official documentation [6.9.5.4 MySQLCursor.execute() Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) has an example query that is very similar to yours.

```
insert_stmt = (
   "INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date) "
   "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
)
data = (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', datetime.date(2012, 3, 23))
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```

In this example, **data** is a **tuple**, not a **list**.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I really apreciate your support it worked for me.